# Jquery select radio on selection

Tags: jquery

I am attempting to through jquery to check and uncheck radio boxes.

For example; when radio ['mainfield'] with the value of '1' is selected – radio ['otherfield'] with the value of 1 to be selected.

Then, if ['mainfield'] is changed on a value other than 1, uncheck the ['otherfield'];

Hopefully what I am after makes sense. Seems simple enough though am not able to really get it to do what I want.

I made a fiddle of my attempt here:
http://jsfiddle.net/brandrally/0zb521v4/2/

**// Javascript //**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('input:radio[name="mainfield"]').change(function(){

    if ($(this).val()==1) {
    $('input:radio[name="otherfield"][value=1].prop('checked', false);
    }

    if ($(this).val()==2) {
    $('input:radio[name="otherfield"][value=1].prop('checked', false);
    }

});
});
```

**// HTML //**

```
<div style="padding: 0 0 10px 0;">
<label><input name="mainfield" type="radio" value="1"> Apples </label>
<label><input name="mainfield" type="radio" value="2"> Oranges</label>
</div>

<div>
<label><input name="otherfield" type="radio" value="1"> Yes [ Automatically Check and Uncheck this box if name='mainfield' = 1 ] </label>
<label><input name="otherfield" type="radio" value="2"> No</label>
</div>
```

Comment: you had a typos on your jsfiddle try this http://jsfiddle.net/crod1nmm/

Comment: Thanks @Parody, It's kind of depressing to make such as rookie error, though appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a stray ') typo that prevented this one from working.